# Difference between CloudBlobDirectory and using a delimiter in Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

What is the difference between using the CloudBlobDirectory and using a Delimited Blob List http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179465.aspx#DelimitedBlobList

When would I use each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own answer is mostly correct.  CloudBlobDirectory is a client-side artifact that comes into play any time you list blobs with a delimiter (not just ListBlobsWithPrefix).  It maps to the `<BlobPrefix>` element that comes back in the body of a (delimited) List Blobs operation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "CloudBlobDirectory" is not an object that is explicitly created on the server, however it is a client side object within the SDK that is retured with  [CloudBlobClient.ListBlobsWithPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg435991.aspx)

Please correct me if I'm mistaken.